# How to remove local directory from git?

Tags: git

I deleted the repository on github and now I'm trying to remove the local directory from git.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDFNN.png)

Comment: How do you normally delete a directory?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the `.git` directory, you can go to your git repo folder and type

`rm -fr .git`

This will remove all of the repository, leaving only the working directory. Make sure you're in the right repo and have a backup to avoid losing files/data.